# Count how many barcodes per day per product

Tags: mysql, group-by, statistics

I have two tables. `barcodes` and `barcodes_entered`

`barcodes`:

```
id | product    | barcode
-------------------------
1  | product1   | 12345
2  | product2   | 23456
3  | product3   | 34567
```

`barcodes_entered`:

```
barcode_id | timestamp 
--------------------------------
2          | 2013-07-01 00:00:00
2          | 2013-07-01 00:00:00
3          | 2013-07-01 00:00:00
2          | 2013-07-02 00:00:00
1          | 2013-07-02 00:00:00
```

I'm trying to figure out how many barcodes were entered per day of each product.

So my expected results from the above would be:

```
product  | count  | date
------------------------------
product1 | 0      | 2013-07-01
product2 | 2      | 2013-07-01
product3 | 1      | 2013-07-01
product1 | 1      | 2013-07-02
product2 | 1      | 2013-07-02
product3 | 0      | 2013-07-02
```

The query I'm attempting to write at the moment looks like this:

```
SELECT product, COUNT( barcode_id ) AS count, DATE(  `timestamp` ) AS date
FROM barcodes_entered
LEFT JOIN barcodes ON barcodes.id = barcodes_entered.barcode_id
GROUP BY DATE(  `timestamp` ) ASC
```

Unfortunately, this gives the following result:

```
product  | count  | date
------------------------------
product1 | 3      | 2013-07-01
product2 | 2      | 2013-07-02
```

So technically I *think* what I'm asking, is **how do I group by Date, then again by Product while counting how many barcodes have been entered of said product?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select from barcodes instead, and join barcodes_entered.
Untested but should work.

```
SELECT product, COUNT( barcode_id ) AS count, DATE(  `timestamp` ) AS date
FROM barcodes
LEFT JOIN barcodes_entered ON barcodes.id = barcodes_entered.barcode_id
GROUP BY DATE(  `timestamp` ) ASC, product
```

Comment: Almost again -- shows the date as `NULL` for those products with zero barcodes at all

Comment: It'll do anyway -- I'll just exclude those with zero from the graph.
Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Group by with both `date` and `product`.

```
GROUP BY DATE(  `timestamp` ) ASC, product
```

**Update**

For getting `zero` in the result, I think you should use `JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Almost -- It doesn't give me back any zeroes (for when there was no barcodes of that product type entered on that date)

Comment: @ahren: please try with `join` instead of `left join`

Comment: Just tried - still no zeroes. This is for outputting a graph (that's why) - cheers